# Error when clicked on dataGridView

Tags: c#

When i click on dataGridView it throws an error saying
 "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."

Here is code section, i need it to, when clicked on some row, to write all parameters in textBoxes so it can be easily updated

```
 private void dgvList_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
                tbName.Text = dgvList.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                tbSurname.Text = dgvList.SelectedRows[1].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                tbMobile.Text = dgvList.SelectedRows[2].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                tbEmail.Text = dgvList.SelectedRows[3].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                cbCategory.Text = dgvList.SelectedRows[4].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that error cause either your gridview don't have 5 rows or 5 columns. How many rows/columns does your gridview has? Remember that array indexing starts with `0`. Make sure, the row number (or) column number you are accessing does exists.

Moreover, why are you accessing multiple rows at same time like below. That don't make sense cause at any time only 1 row will be selected. ... Right?

```
dgvList.SelectedRows[0]
dgvList.SelectedRows[1]
```

It rather should be probably be

```
 private void dgvList_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
                tbName.Text = dgvList.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                tbSurname.Text = dgvList.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                tbMobile.Text = dgvList.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                tbEmail.Text = dgvList.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                cbCategory.Text = dgvList.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        }
```

Thanks @stackuser83 for pointing that.

Comment: @stackuser83, Yes correct. Edited answer. Thanks for pointing.